# Java/1.7.0_07 as user agent

Tags: security, user-agent

almost every day something (it should be a bot) visits all of my pages on my website (amongst other things it doesn't correctly handle spaces in urls) with Java/1.7.0_07 (or different java versions) as referrer.

Should I worry? Should I block by useragent anything that contains "Java"?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be Java crawler. Anyone could have written it or used existing one. I would say you don't need to worry as www is kind of "read only" so no crawl will harm your page. However this is possible way for stealing content or analyse it for an undesired purpose.

It depends on you, will you block it :)